# Can't access the sharepoint list items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to access list items to check if an item is document set or not but when I execute the following code, debugger does leave the code when I want to access a list item, according to the forums they say that is a matter of security:

```
SPListItemCollection itms = list.Items;

 for (int i = 0; i < itms.ItemCount; i++)
  {
      SPListItem item = itms[i];//here exit 
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: yeah i'm debugging with web app administrator

Comment: i got the error System.StackOverflowException

Comment: the error is An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException exception occurred in module unknown.

Comment: Have you tried the foreach way?

Comment: yeah indeed i did

Comment: Do you want to fetch only document sets or you want to fetch all items and check one by one?

Comment: i want to get only document sets